# Mongodb java find document and filter an array field (delete array data that don't match a condition)

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I try to request a Collection but impossible to filter the embedded array. I would like to get every Documents in the Collection that match {"players.nick" : nick } and filter the 'players' array to get only the searched player inside.

Here is the intial Document :

```
{"_id":2000,"type":3,"prizepool":6520.5,"name":"XXX","start":1515701700,"end":1515719580,"buyin":2.25,"rake":0.5,"prize":0,"bounty":2.25,"players":[{"nick":"player1","rank":1,"cash":660.85,"kill":468.64,"ticket":0,"reentry":0},{"nick":"player2","rank":2,"cash":430.35,"kill":101.31,"ticket":0,"reentry":0},{"nick":"player3","rank":3,"cash":312.98,"kill":72.26,"ticket":0,"reentry":0},{"nick":"player4","rank":4,"cash":237.99,"kill":27.15,"ticket":0,"reentry":1}]}
```

And after requesting I would like to retrieve :

```
{"_id":2000,"type":3,"prizepool":6520.5,"name":"XXX","start":1515701700,"end":1515719580,"buyin":2.25,"rake":0.5,"prize":0,"bounty":2.25,"players":[{"nick":"player1","rank":1,"cash":660.85,"kill":468.64,"ticket":0,"reentry":0}}
```

Does anyone know how to do that in a java way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation pipeline in java.

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mc.getDatabase(db);
MongoCollection col = db.getCollection(col);
```

For single match you can use `$elemMatch` projection

```
col.find().projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("_id","type", "prizepool","name","start","end","buyin","rake","prize","bounty"),
                Projections.elemMatch("players", Filters.eq("nick", "player1"))));
```

For both single & multiple matches

```
Bson filter = new Document("players", Document.parse("{\n" +
            "            $filter: {\n" +
            "               input: \"$players\",\n" +
            "               as: \"player\",\n" +
            "               cond: { $eq: [ \"$$player.nick\", \"player1\" ] }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "         }"));
Bson addFields = new Document("$addFields", filter);
col.aggregate(Arrays.asList(addFields));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works perfectly... I was working on it the entire day... You rock !

Comment: @DavidB if this answer work for you "accept" it, that's the way to thank on SO and it also the correct indication for other users that you solved it using this. (never add solved to title of question)